# PHP: remove seconds off of returned time value

Tags: php

I need to remove the seconds off of a returned time value. I get

```
12:00:00
```

I want

```
12:00pm
```

I tried using `date()` but it kept returning the time as 1:00am for everything.

```
echo date('g:ia', $timestamp);
```

Comment: what is your question again ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) -

```
echo date('g:ia', strtotime($timestamp));
```

The [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function  - `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )` - where `$timestamp` is to be an integer Unix timestamp.

Comment: I lost the am pm part of my timestamp

Answer (score 15):

```
$timestamp = $timestamp - ($timestamp % 60);
```

In other words, use the modulo function to substract the number of seconds in the current minute from the time.

Somtimes, simpler is better (and a lot more efficient than strtotime).

Comment: my time changed to 00 when I tried this

Comment: What do you mean, 'time'? This only works for integer timestamps, not strings.

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to remove seconds (not PM needed), you can use both MYSQL or php:

MYSQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds), 1, 5);
```

PHP:

```
$cleantime=substr($time,0,-3);
```

both will strip off seconds and keep hours and minutes

*thanks to Jahanzeb for enhancing the PHP version to support also > 99 hours*

Comment: just to add more details,

$cleantime=substr($time,0,5)   
this does not work fine in case anyone wants to sum total time, 
e.g i was trying to sum up time and it does not show time  properly (124:25)  and it will display only 124:2

Comment: by practising to get a better way to deal with such use case, i came up with a result that we can use  $cleantime=substr($time,0,-3) and that will smoothly remove last 3 characters as we are dealing it as a string.  i.e :00 will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `strtotime()`?

```
echo date( 'g:ia', strtotime("12:00:00") );
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer this approach:

```
 private function floorMinute(DateTimeImmutable $dateTime): DateTimeImmutable
 {
     return $dateTime->modify(sprintf('-%d seconds', (int)$dateTime->format('s')));
 }
```

This could be altered/extended to round up.